# R data.table get unique id with maximum other id

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` like so:

```
id | id2 | val
--------------
 1 |   1 |   A
 1 |   2 |   B
 2 |   3 |   C
 2 |   4 |   D
 3 |   5 |   E
 3 |   6 |   F
```

I want to group by the `id` column, and return the maximum `id2` for that `id. Like so:

```
id | id2 | val
--------------
 1 |   2 |   B
 2 |   4 |   D
 3 |   6 |   F
```

It's easy in SQL:

```
SELECT id, MAX(id2) FROM tbl GROUP BY id;
```

But I want to know how to do this with `data.table`. So far I have:

```
tbl[, .(id2 = max(id2)), by = id]
```

but I don't know how to get the val part.

Comment: `tbl[, .SD[id2 = max(id2)], by = id]`

Comment: @Jaap Replace the `=` after `id2` with `==`.

Comment: @Jaap didn't work... `Error in \`[.data.table\`(.SD, id2 = max(id2)) : unused argument(id2 = max(id2))`

Comment: Use `==` as Jason suggested.

Comment: @JasonMorgan sorry, it is a typo; i’m typing on my phone :-/

Comment: Ah ok it worked. Thanks! Make this an answer and I'll mark as ans?

Comment: No, there is a duplicate for this

Comment: Agree with Jaap, there must be a dupe. Another common answer to this: `unique(df[order(id2)], by="id", fromLast=TRUE)`

Comment: @Frank this requires the `setkey` command to be used first. I mistakenly thought the `by` parameter took care of this, but it does not.

Comment: @user3685285 I don't follow. If you want the result sorted by `id` you can also use `setorder` or write `order(id1, id2)` in place of `order(id2)`. Or there's `df[order(id2), .SD[.N], keyby=id]` ... there are many approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- read.table(header = T, text = "id  id2  val
                 1    1    A
                 1    2    B
                 2    3    C
                 2    4    D
                 3    5    E
                 3    6    F")
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, max_id2 := max(id2), by = id]
df <- df[id2 == max_id2, ]
df[, max_id2 := NULL]




    id id2 val
1:  1   2   B
2:  2   4   D
3:  3   6   F
```